# Count Two Column Values Based on One Same Column in Two tables in mysql

Tags: mysql, count, multiple-columns

Situation is like this:

Table One (sms)

```
id  |  t_id  |  sms_text
1   |   200  |  some text here ...
2   |   201  |  some text here ...
3   |   202  |  some text here ...
4   |   201  |  some text here ...
5   |   202  |  some text here ...
6   |   202  |  some text here ...
```

Table Two (msg)

```
id  |  t_id  |  msg_text
1   |   201  |  some text here ...
2   |   202  |  some text here ...
3   |   200  |  some text here ...
4   |   200  |  some text here ...
5   |   202  |  some text here ...
6   |   200  |  some text here ...
```

Now I Want Result Something Similar

Count Result (sms + msg)

```
t_id | count result
200  |  4
201  |  3
202  |  5
```

Is is possible?? If yes, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can - for example - use a `UNION ALL` to get the t_id's from both tables, and just `COUNT` them;

```sql
SELECT t_id, COUNT(*) `count`
FROM (
  SELECT t_id FROM Table1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT t_id FROM Table2
) dummy
GROUP BY t_id
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/257d3/3).